# How to find out whether the frame exists or not

Tags: java, selenium

In my application, all the tabs are categories under one frame. I used:

```java
driver.switchTo().frame((WebElement) By.name("contents"));
System.out.println("Frame is selected");
```

to verify the frame exists, but I am getting the following exception:

```
>Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:      
    org.openqa.selenium.By$ByName cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement
    at selenium_test.iebrowser.main(iebrowser.java:75)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error says that you are trying to cast a `By` from your `By.name("contents")`, to a `WebElement` from your`(WebElement)` ... which of course is nonesense!

According to the [Selenium API](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/index.html?org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.TargetLocator.html), `.switchTo().frame()` has one of the following signatures:

```
WebDriver frame(int index);
WebDriver frame(String nameOrId);
WebDriver frame(WebElement frameElement);
```

What you need is either *one* of these:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("contents");  // uses the nameOrId
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("contents")));  // uses the frameElement
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use browser's deve window(F12) and search inside the `html` if the html contains `iframe` or such

> For this hit F12>Click inside the html source>Ctrl+F for search and type whatever you want to search.

See [this](http://screencast.com/t/hsTIISxs)

Additionally just for the clarification, Verify the element inside the `iframe`. `contents` does not seems like a valid `iframe` name to me. Provide relevant html to investigate further